# Spring batch jsr 352 skip-limit how to get unlimited default or set unlimited

Tags: spring-batch, jsr352

I am trying to figure out how to set an unlimited value for skip-limit with out just randomly defining a very large integer value.

The jsr 352 specifically states "The default is no limit." but I have not figure out how to get a default when actually defining a skippable exception.

I tried 0 and -1 but both fail the positive number validation that spring batch does on the step when creating the job.  If the skip-limit attribute is not added when you have skippable exception defined it generates an error and does not start the job.

Am i misinterpreting what the specification is saying or is spring batch not implementing the jsr correctly in this instance.  It definitely appears on the surface that skip-limit should have some means of defaulting to an unlimited value.

Answer (score 6):

Your could do something like:

```
public class ItemSkipPolicy implements SkipPolicy {

public boolean shouldSkip(final Throwable t, final int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
    return true;
}
```

and use the skip policy instead of the skipLimit

```
.faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new ItemSkipPolicy()).skip(RuntimeException.class)
```

hopfully this helps if someone else sees this page

Comment: There is into spring batch package a  Implementation of the SkipPolicy interface that
will always return that an item should be skipped.

.faultTolerant().skipPolicy(**new AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy()**).skip(RuntimeException.class)

Answer (score 2):

From the [JSR](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/batch-1_0-fr-eval-spec/) :

> **skip-limit** : Specifies the number of exceptions a step will skip if any configured skippable
>   exceptions are thrown by chunk processing. It must be a valid XML integer value.
>   It is an optional attribute. The default is no limit.

If you respect the JSR in spring batch you should have this behavior. if you will don't follow the JSR, you face the [BATCH-2443](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2443).

Comment: using faultTolerant().skip(Exception.class) without specifying the skipLimit attribute means that the default value is 0:  org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipLimitExceededException: Skip limit of '0' exceeded

Answer (score 1):

The skip-limit is an integer, so as far as you dont exceed the max value, you could for this as a value: #{T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE}. Not providing a skip limit in your step configuration would raise an error by Spring batch :

```
The field 'skippable-exception-classes' is not permitted on the step [stepName] because there is no 'skip-limit'.
```